# How to remove %20 in alertview ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uialertview

in ios alertview i have %20 symbol how to remove this..

[image]

this is my code

```
NSString *titile = result;
NSString *notifiText=txtresult;

alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:notifiText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil, nil];
                [alertView show]
```

i just want output like this instead of %20 i want space..

Comment: can u post **notifiText** text here. And also post the desired output that u want

Comment: i mean to say post the **"txtresult"**, means the string which u want to show in the alert view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're likely retrieving your alert text from the web or from a JSON/XML response, the string is coming in encoded with "percent escapes".  You need to remove them before displaying your alert.

And lucky for you, NSString has a handy method named [`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a) (I've linked Apple's documentation).

Answer (score 4):

You must be getting your message text from an NSURLConnection or some web service, try using the following:

```
notifiText = [notifiText stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

See [**`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)

Answer (score 1):

There is a method introduced in iOS 7 (and OS X 10.9) called [stringByRemovingPercentEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1409569-stringbyremovingpercentencoding?language=objc)

which automatically uses the `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.